# Robolectric: “AndroidManifest.xml not found” and "Unable to find resource ID #0x7f09001b"

Tags: android, compiler-errors, android-manifest, robolectric

I'm running some tests with Roboletric, but I came across a issue that I can't solve.
When I run the test, the following error appears with the "AndroidManifest":

> WARNING: No manifest file found at .\AndroidManifest.xml.
>
> Falling back to the Android OS resources only. To remove this warning, annotate
>   your test class with @Config(manifest=Config.NONE).
>
> No such manifest file: .\AndroidManifest.xml

I've tried these solutions that **failed**:

```
@Config (manifest = Config.DEFAULT_MANIFEST_NAME)

@Config(manifest = Config.NONE, constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 26)

@Config( constants = BuildConfig.class, manifest="src/main/AndroidManifest.xml", sdk = 26 )
```

And the other error during execution is:

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find
>   resource ID #0x7f09001b in packages [android, org.robolectric.default]

...

> at
>
> com.example.robertoassad.alltestsmerge.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52)

This line that have the error is the following code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

**Specifically** in:  `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

For me I didn't see sense in this issue ...

DETAILS:

- The test class is on the folder: `app\src\test\java\com\example\robertoassad`
- The test is: 

  `@RunWith( RobolectricTestRunner.class)
  public class Roboletric {`

       `@Test
       public void clickingLogin_shouldStartLoginActivity() {
           MainActivity activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(MainActivity.class);
           activity.findViewById(R.id.button2).performClick();`

  ```
          Intent expectedIntent = new Intent(activity, SecondActivity.class);
          Intent actual = ShadowApplication.getInstance().getNextStartedActivity();
          assertEquals(expectedIntent.getComponent(), actual.getComponent());
       }
  ```

  `}`

Comment: Do you have any test working with robolectric?

Comment: Do you run it in AS?

Comment: @LeandroOcampo No...

Comment: @EugenMartynov sorry, but what is AS ?

Comment: @RobertoPinheiro tell me which operative system you are using

Comment: @LeandroOcampo Windows 7.

Comment: @RobertoPinheiro have you checked the issue on mac and linux? http://robolectric.org/getting-started/  under "Note for Linux and Mac Users". I know it is windows but it may worth giving a try.

Comment: @LeandroOcampo I did not seen this note, I do not have any device with another operating system, I will try to get one, but I find it very difficult ... But, thank you very much, I did not realize that note ... But would you have any suggestions on how to fix this on windows?

Comment: not at the moment but try to set android studio with that configuration and see if it helps.

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar problem to the one you face. The [post by jongerrish](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/3169#issuecomment-312046322) on the Robolectric GitHub Issue about this resolved the problem for me.

The aspect of the answer that worked for me was to add a `testOptions` block in my module's `build.gradle` file:

```
testOptions {
    unitTests {
        includeAndroidResources = true
    }
}
```

After adding this block my tests were able to run and access String resources.

Answer (score 2):

This problem bug me for some time, and here is my note in my test code.

## About manifest location

With Gradle build system, Robolectric looks for AndroidManifest.xml in the following order.

- Java resource folder
- build/intermediates/manifests/[full or fast-start]/[build-type]

So it is a common mistake to specify the location of AndroidManifest.xml according to source code folder organization (e.g. src/main/AndroidManifest.xml) . The specified AndroidManifest.xml location affect how Robolectric look for merged resources as well. So if some resource is not found in test, it is probably due to incorrect setting of AndroidManifest.xml location.

That said, the Android Gradle plugin merge the AndroidManifest.xml and put the result under the above mentioned intermediates directory. So the content of src/main/AndroidManifest.xml affect the test result.

So if you want to specify manifest option in @Config, just use @Config(manifest=“AndroidManifest.xml”) should probably be fine. If you want to use an alternate AndroidManifest.xml, put it in Java resources folder, and specify @Config according to the relative path in resources folder.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same problem while testing my library module from app. Now my Receievers and Service are in my library, so to test those , i had to implement custom Test Class, so Roboelectric can point to my library manifest and not the app manifest :

```
import android.os.Build;
import org.junit.runners.model.InitializationError;
import org.robolectric.manifest.AndroidManifest;
import org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner;
import org.robolectric.annotation.Config;
import org.robolectric.res.Fs;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class RobolectricGradleTestRunner extends RobolectricTestRunner {
    private static final String PROJECT_DIR =
            "C:/MyProject/";


    private static final int MAX_SDK_SUPPORTED_BY_ROBOLECTRIC =
            Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2;

    public RobolectricGradleTestRunner(final Class<?> testClass) throws Exception {
        super(testClass);
    }

    private static AndroidManifest getAndroidManifest() {

        String manifestPath = PROJECT_DIR+"/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml";
        String resPath = PROJECT_DIR+"/src/main/res";
        String assetPath = PROJECT_DIR+"/src/main/assets";

        System.out.print("manifest path: "+manifestPath);
        System.out.print("resPath path: "+resPath);
        System.out.print("assetPath path: "+assetPath);

        return new AndroidManifest(
                Fs.fileFromPath(manifestPath), Fs.fileFromPath(resPath), Fs.fileFromPath(assetPath)) {
            @Override public int getTargetSdkVersion() {
                return MAX_SDK_SUPPORTED_BY_ROBOLECTRIC;
            }
        };
    }

    private static String getProjectDirectory() {
        String path = "";
        try {
            File file = new File("..");
            path = file.getCanonicalPath();
            path = path + "/app/";
        } catch (IOException ex) {}
        return path;
    }

    @Override public AndroidManifest getAppManifest(Config config) {
        return getAndroidManifest();
    }
}
```

and use it in your test class like :

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
public class MyClassChangeTest {
}
```