# illegalArguments - cannot find manifest in robolectric

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-testing, robolectric

I am running android unit test and try to test the ability to check run time permissions in Android. I thought that will be straight forward to just create a test manifest under `test` folder (NOT `androidTest` folder).
like this,

[image]

However, it throws exceptions `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: failed to configure ..mysdk.myTest.myTest: couldn't find 'mysdk/src/test/AndroidManifest.xml'`

I had googled this for couple of days and couldn't find the right solution for it. I had read couple of threads on stackoverflow as well. But non of them works for me ( set `$MODULE_DIR$`, reset unit test in `Edit Configuration`...etc)

Here is the test code and I simply use Android Studio without build the project to run the test cases. (it works fine for non-manifest related test cases)

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, manifest =
    "mysdk/src/test/AndroidManifest.xml")
public class myTest {
private Context context;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    context = RuntimeEnvironment.application;
}

@Test
public void myTest() throws JSONException {
    boolean hasWifiPermission context.checkCallingOrSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.INTERNET)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    assertTrue(hasWifiPermission);
}


java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: failed to configure 

mycompany.mysdk.myTest.mytest: couldn't find 'mysdk/src/test/AndroidManifest.xml'
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.getChildren(RobolectricTestRunner.java:256)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.getFilteredChildren(ParentRunner.java:426)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.getDescription(ParentRunner.java:351)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.getDescription(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:50)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: couldn't find 'mysdk/src/test/AndroidManifest.xml'
    at org.robolectric.internal.DefaultManifestFactory.resolveFile(DefaultManifestFactory.java:58)
    at org.robolectric.internal.DefaultManifestFactory.identify(DefaultManifestFactory.java:32)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.getAppManifest(RobolectricTestRunner.java:402)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.getChildren(RobolectricTestRunner.java:243)
    ... 12 more
```

I am using Android Studio 3.0.1 and Roboletric 3.5.1.

Comment: just try manifest=“AndroidManifest.xml” https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47456711/robolectric-androidmanifest-xml-not-found-and-unable-to-find-resource-id-0x/47605226#47605226

Comment: I would remove manifest specification. I would use latest Robolectric 3.6.1 and follow page how to setup it

Comment: @thinkpanda thanks!
saved my life!